# Capistrano and API keys in ENV variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, environment-variables, capistrano

I'm deploying my rails app with Capistrano. I want to save some API keys on the server as an environment variable. Those API keys should be accessible to my rails app that is deployed with Capistrano. Those API keys should also be accessible to a separate ruby file that is run as a daemon.

setting the API keys in environment variables seems like the ideal solution, however, I can't access them in my rails app with `ENV["SOME_KEY"]`.

According to [this post](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/), because capistrano runs as non interactive and non login, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` are not loaded. The flowchart suggests that I should use `$BASH_ENV`.

Can I just add my api keys in `$BASH_ENV` and access them in my rails app and in the ruby file that is a daemon with `ENV["SOME_KEY"]`?

I'm also thinking of just adding the api keys to a file somewhere on the server and symlinking it to the ruby file dir and rails dir and just open and reading it. Would this be possible?

Comment: I personally have opted to store secrets and such in files in a directory that is not included in the version-control system after experimenting with getting the environment variables to be properly propagated. Just be careful!

Comment: Checkout the dotenv gem, it basically does what @ollpu said to do.  https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: @ollpu: So basically adding the files manually to the rails dir after deploy? How do you read those files after you added them to the dir?

Comment: Check the documentation for the server os. There almost always is a way to set ENV vars in a shell independent way.

Comment: For example you could add them to `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/environments`. please tell what OS you are using on your server for detailed instructions.

Comment: @max i'm using centos 6.5

Answer (score 27):

There are a few ways that work well with Capistrano, in my experience.

**rbenv-vars**

If you use Ruby via Rbenv on your server, then you are in luck. There is a Rbenv plugin called [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars) that automatically injects environment variables into any Ruby process, which would include your Rails app. Just add your variables to `~/.rbenv/vars` on the server using `KEY=value` syntax. That's it.

**dotenv**

The [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem is a similar solution, but it works as a gem you add to your Rails app and doesn't require Rbenv or any other supporting tools. Add `dotenv-rails` to your Gemfile and deploy. Dotenv will automatically look for a `.env.production` file in the root of your Rails app. For Capistrano, create a `.env.production` file on the server inside Capistrano's `shared` directory, and then add `.env.production` to `:linked_files`. Now every deploy will link to it. Declare your variables using `KEY=value` syntax.

**.bashrc**

Declare your variables with `export KEY=value` syntax at very top of the `~/.bashrc` file on the server. On Ubuntu, this file is evaluated even during an non-interactive SSH session. Just make sure you place the declarations on the top, before this case statement:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

CentOS may be a different story, so YMMV.

Comment: dotenv sounds good, but how do I test it locally before deploying?

Comment: dotenv works the same way locally. Just put KEY=value variables in `.env.development` in the root of your Rails project and then start the app normally with `rails server`. Those variables will be loaded and available through `ENV`. You might need to run `spring stop` first to guarantee a cold boot.

Answer (score 2):

I made a Capistrano plugin [`capistrano-env_config`](https://github.com/itay-grudev/capistrano-env_config) some time ago for managing and syncing environment variables across a Capistrano cluster which works by modifying the `/etc/environment` file to make environment variables available throughout the system. It's easy to use and is similar to how you can set environment variables with the Heroku toolbelt. Here are some examples:

```
cap env:list
cap env:get[VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_NAME, ...] 
cap env:unset[VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_NAME, ...] 
cap env:set[VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE, VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE, ...] 
cap env:sync
```