# Capistrano not setting env vars AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I currently have an app deployed with capistrano in an EC2 instance in AWS.

For some reason, some of the ENV VARS are not set when the app runs. If I connect via SSH and do a `printenv` or use the rails console, the ENV VARs do show properly. But for the running app, the ENV VARs do not show.

I've got little experience with Capistrano and EC2 so I'm not entirely sure what code should I share and I don't know where to check if my configuration is properly done.

How do I set up the environment variables so that they are accesible for the deployed application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer here: [Capistrano and API keys in ENV variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624035/capistrano-and-api-keys-in-env-variables/39628182#39628182)

I had to follow any of the methods described there to set the env vars. I've actually followed the second method, using the *dotenv* gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variables for capistrano session:

```
set :default_environment, { 
 'environment_variable_1' => 'value_1',
 'environment_variable_2' => 'value_2'
}
```

Comment: And where do I put that?

Comment: try adding in deploy.rb

Comment: I did this and they were not added to the ENV. I print the ENV variable in Rails and they do not appear (neither do the vars that i mention on the post)

Comment: does setting it in inside deploy folder for current environment (eg: production.rb) have any effect?