# Sidekiq deployment fails with "key not found: "MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, sidekiq

This is my rookie first question to the community.

**Background:**

I try to deploy Sidekiq on a my own Jessie Debian server for a Rails 5.0.6 app that works with Phusion Passenger with a user "deploy" . I have Redis 3.2.6 installed and tested ok. I've opted for a Systemd daemon to start Sidekiq as a system service. 
Here is the configuration :

```
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/my_app/code
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml'
User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002

# if we crash, restart
RestartSec=4
#Restart=on-failure
Restart=always

# output goes to /var/log/syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

# This will default to "bundler" if we don't specify it
SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is sidekiq.yml

```
---
:verbose: true
:concurrency: 4
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:queues:
  - [critical, 2]
  - default
  - low

production:
  :concurrency: 15
```

And finally  #config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['SITE']}:6379/0", password: ENV['REDIS_PWD'] }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['SITE']}:6379/0", password: ENV['REDIS_PWD'] }
end
```

**How it fails**
I've been trying to solve the following error found in /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec 18 00:13:39 jjflo systemd[1]: Started sidekiq.
Dec 18 00:13:48 jjflo sidekiq[8159]: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Dec 18 00:13:48 jjflo sidekiq[8159]: key not found: "MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD"
```

which ends up in a sequence of sidekiq failure and a retry...

**Yet another try**
I have tried the following and *this works* :

```
cd /var/www/my_app/code
su - deploy
/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml'
```

Could someone help me connect the dots, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variable were obviously the problem. Since I was using

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle...
```

where -l was refering to a bash interactive session, I had to get into .bashrc of deploy user to move the export lines at **the top of the file** instead of the bottom where they used to be, or at least before this line of .bashrc :

```
case $- in
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624035/capistrano-and-api-keys-in-env-variables/39628182#39628182) helped me a lot.